# jQuery Validation plugin - Validating hidden inputs and not visible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How would I validate hidden inputs and not visible text inputs with jQuery Form Validation plugin? The problem is, that I'm using auto-suggest plugin, which generates a hidden input for selected items:

```
<input id="hiddenInput" type="hidden" name="something" value="1" />
```

I have 2 inputs like this (both of them only allow 1 item), which I want to validate and display the error in parent `<td>`.
This is what I've gotten so far, but it doesn't display the error or submit a form, if the value is actually a number.

```
$("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            something: {
                number:true,
                min:1,
                required:true
            }
        }
        })
```

Comment: You should consider selecting one of the posts as Answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

To allow validation of hidden elements, override the ignore and set it to empty string:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        something: {
            number:true,
            min:1,
            required:true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this? because this is giving an error when I use ignore : "". `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`

Comment: By default, for the last several years, this plugin will ignore (not validate) all hidden fields.  The proper format to tell the plugin to ignore nothing and validate everything is `ignore: []`

Answer (score 30):

You can use `ignore` option like this:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden",
    rules: {
        something: {
            number:true,
            min:1,
            required:true
        }
    }
});
```

Default value of `ignore` option is `:hidden` which ignores all hidden fields and non-visible fields (`display: none` etc.)

Comment: Still doesn't validate. I add a rule to a hidden input and make sure it's not valid, but it still submits the form and no errors are shown at all!

Comment: @EmreErkan Documentation link is hosed now.

Answer (score 15):

If the other answers aren't working for you, try this instead. It removes all ignores for the form, so it would validate everything including hidden fields:

```
$.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings.ignore = "";
```

To restore the settings to ignore hidden fields, use something like this:

```
$.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings.ignore = "input[type='text']:hidden";
```

You can also use the above code to read back the current value.

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work for me. It gives me `TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined`, I've checked `$` and it's proper jQuery object. Here is an alternative answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/1027198.

Comment: Oddly enough, your solution is the *only* one that worked for me - none of the other answers did.

Comment: Confirmed working with Aspnet Core 3.1 MVC application

Answer (score 5):

Another way to validate hidden inputs is this:

```
$("#form1").validate({
        ignore: "not:hidden",
        rules: {
            something: {
                number:true,
                min:1,
                required:true
            }
        }
});
```