# jquery validate hidden field for a specific word

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Validation plugin - Validating hidden inputs and not visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952181/jquery-validation-plugin-validating-hidden-inputs-and-not-visible)

I'm trying to validate a hidden text field for a specific word using equalTo, but it seems to be validating false. What's the right way to do this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="aImg" value="true" class="aImg">

$("#artcForm").validate({

        rules: {

            aImg: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "true"
            },
        },
```

Comment: I've already set ignore: [], in the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Norman see working sample here for you case **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rgHkD/

So in `equalTo` attribute I am comparing the default value of hidden field - click on the "contibue step 2" for the validation.

Hope it fits the need! `:)`

**code**

```
   $('form').validate({
       ignore: "",
       rules: {
           first_nameo: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#FirstName"
            },
           first_name: {
                required: true
           },
            last_name: "required",
            address: "required"
        }
    });
```

**image** When you type false it will fail

[image]

**Success when you type true in first name text box**

[image]

Comment: This is the way it is right now. We're using two hidden fields. So there's no way to make it look for a specific word without using two hidden fields?

Comment: AHa! Hiya @Norman there is a way see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation add the new method to your rules and then you can do whateven you feel like. `:)` hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

check this, you have to add another hidden field with you prerequested value:

```
<input name="h1" type="hidden" disabled="disabled" class="required" id="h1" value="your value"/>

<input name="h2" type="hidden" disabled="disabled" class="required"  equalTo="#h1" id="h2" value=""/>
```

[jquery ref](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-proper-use-of-equalto-along-with-required)

hope it work:)

Comment: I did this before and it works. Wonder why it wont work if we gave it a word.

Comment: the jquery equalto take the id not the value. its a compare validator. you have to implement it yourself.