# jquery form Validate wouldn't work using tabs in page

Tags: jquery, validation, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have a simple POST form that is being validated using Validate library from jquery, and it all works fine, but then I used the tabs function from bootstrap and many other libraries to separate the form into two different tabs. The problem now is that validation happens only to the open (visible) tab, regardless the condition of the other input fields in hidden tabs.
Any possible suggestions?

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643500/jquery-validation-multiple-tabs-validate-one-at-a-time

Comment: yes it will only validate your visible field, you can use form wizard for your use

Comment: very helpful question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think your trouble might be that jquery by default will only validate visible fields. So what you need to do is tell jquery to not ignore your hidden fields (other tabs). This can be done as follows:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: ""
});
```

By default `ignore: ":hidden"`. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952181/jquery-validation-plugin-validating-hidden-inputs-and-not-visible), and [this documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) (Options -> Ignore).

Answer (score 3):

Please see the accepted answer above, it is really helpful. 
Just in case of using `unobtrusive validation`, then the accepted answer will not work, and here is the solution.

```
$("#form1").data("validator").settings.ignore = "";
```

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053251/4390133)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. I've been seeing the solution from accepted answer everywhere and was wondering why it's not working for me. cheers!